# I don't understand why using " " in my code works, but the same code with ' ' does not

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Here is the code I am using:

```
with open(os.path.join(my_path, 'pastimes.csv'), 'r') as my_file:
    my_file_reader = csv.DictReader(my_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in my_file_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {', '.join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'{row['Person']} has a favourite pastime of {row['Favourite Pastime']}.')
        line_count += 1
```

The above does not work, but the below works:

```
with open(os.path.join(my_path, 'pastimes.csv'), mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'{row["Person"]} has a favourite pastime of {row["Favourite Pastime"]}.')
        line_count += 1
```

I simply can't figure out why!

Comment: You should use a better IDE, or a programming text editor which provides at least lexical highlighting, or better syntax highlighting or even semantic highlighting. Even the extremely simplistic and crappy lexical highlighting on [so] already clearly shows the difference right here in your question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that is a good point. I shall take that on board :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
f'Column names are {', '.join(row)}'
```

In above statement, `'Col ... {'` this is one string but in

```py
f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}'
```

Now `'Col...}'` string

Its because string is in between pair of `'`  and your pair is closing string before actual string ends.

You can also use following

```py
f'Column names are {\', \'.join(row)}'
```

Comment: Awesome. Broken my head over this one for an hour. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chadmeistr - This is also known as "quoting hell" especially if you need to handle more than two-level nested `" ' \" \' \\\" \\\' \\\\\"` quotes

Comment: @slebetman that does look like hell. I'll get to it at some point :D

Comment: If you got your answer Please think about accepting it.

Comment: @Chadmeistr Yeah, most languages don't really have solutions to this but I like how Tcl side-steps this issue by using `{` and `}` as string quote marks which allow nested strings inside strings. A slightly less *neat* solution is Perl's ability to let you choose your own string quote marks with the `qq` and `qw` operators: `qq[this is a string]`, `qq|this is also a string|`

Comment: @slebetman: Ruby stole^H^H^H^H^H was inspired by Perl as well. It's a life-saver when composing complex template strings.